# Action Mailer production.rb not working when deployed via Sendgrid and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer

I'm currently in the process of trying to send Account Confirmation emails to any new user that creates an account on my Rails app.

I've successfully deployed locally via development.rb, but for some reason I get an error message every time "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information". I've reviewed several resources both here on Stack Overflow as well as Heroku, Youtube and have not been able to find a solution.

Here is my code in environments/production.rb:

```
# Don't care if the mailer can't send.
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
port: 587,
domain: ENV["SENDGRID_DOMAIN"],
authentication: "plain",
enable_starttls_auto: true,
user_name: ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
password: ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"]
}

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => "<myherokuappname>.herokuapp.com/"}


config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
```

Again just to confirm, I am able to deploy emails locally, just not at the production level. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently integrated SendGrid into my Heroku app too. My production.rb settings are as follows:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: '<myherokuappname>.herokuapp.com' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain => '<myherokuappname>.herokuapp.com',
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

I tested this out just a few minutes ago and it sends fine.